# older jPanel vanish when jFrame is refreshed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am coding an intense game and have an important question. In this game, thanks to searching and finding the `revalidate()` method and the `repaint()` method I have managed to successfully remove a `JPanel` and place another `JPanel` in it's place.

However... this is where the problems begin. I am able to do this, but there are multiple (can range from 9 to 729) such JPanels that need to be changed. I am able to do this in the JFrame no problem... however the issue I am currently facing is that although one JPanel is replaced properly, when I do the next one it is also replaced properly. However, after multiple tests I found that when the JFrame is refreshed by dragging it off and back on screen or any other such change the older changed JPanels vanish.

Is there any way that I can make the newly added JPanel's permanently there rather than vanishing if and only if the JFrame is refreshed??

Here is the code:

```
int a = f%27;
int b = g%27;
int c = a%9;
int d = b%9;
winningletter.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 17));
miniwin.add(winningletter);
((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[f/27][g/27].getComponent((a/9)*3+b/9)).getComponent((c/3)*3+d/3)).removeAll();
((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[f/27][g/27].getComponent((a/9)*3+b/9)).getComponent((c/3)*3+d/3)).setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[f/27][g/27].getComponent((a/9)*3+b/9)).getComponent((c/3)*3+d/3)).add(miniwin);
((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[f/27][g/27].getComponent((a/9)*3+b/9)).getComponent((c/3)*3+d/3)).repaint();
metametametaminiminiwincheck[f/3][g/3]=winningletter.getText();
boardChanger(f, g, 4);
WinChecker(s, f,g,3,4,metametametaminiminiwincheck,x);
```

Comment: Without relevant code, we can only speculate. And the programming gods would punish us for that: our keyboards would dissapear and we would be stuck with touchscreens which, for people like us, it would be comparable to forcing Michael Schumacher to drive an electric car (not even a hybrid).

Comment: Too less information :S Need source code to see where the problem may be... Is your panel static?

Comment: @user2190592 I edited my answer. Watch it please

Answer (score 1):

You should be using **CardLayout**: `The CardLayout class manages two or more components (usually JPanel instances) that share the same display space.`

It enables you to flip between panels the pro way. Each JPanel has an ID and you can display it using it.

**link:** 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

**Code:**

```
//Where instance variables are declared:
JPanel cards;
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "BUTTONPANEL";
final static String TEXTPANEL = "TEXTPANEL";

//Where the components controlled by the CardLayout are initialized:
//Create the "cards".
JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
JPanel card2 = new JPanel();

//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);
```

**Calling the JPanel to display:**

```
 CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
 cl.show(cards, BUTTONPANEL);
```

Comment: Ok... I got JPanel to work... my only question is how to retrieve the shown panel? like how to find that it is card1 it using cards.getShown() or something like that??

Comment: First you have to mark the question as answered so other users may benefit from the answer. To get the active panel you should use a global variable that stores the string when you call the show method. for example: cl.show(cards, BUTTONPANEL); 
 String currentPanel = BUTTONPANEL;

Comment: No... no... how do I retrieve the panel that is not used in cl.show()... like find just that alarm... like... card.getComponent(1) or something??

Comment: Hello Alexi... thank you very much for answering my question... but even if I apply cl.show(card, "TextPanel"); nothing changes... why????

Comment: it is case sensitive.. follow the tutorial in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

> I found that when the JFrame is refreshed by dragging it off and back
>   on screen or any other such change the older changed JPanels vanish

Emm... it seems naturally that UI repaint() method is being invoked authomatically after you re-size JFrame etc :)

> thanks to searching and finding the revalidate() method and the
>   repaint() method I have managed to successfully remove a JPanel

It is quite strange you point your code strategy for the graphics2d only :S If you don't need to paint a new UI every time but **keep** them , as I could get it, inited in the heap **not to re-init** to set into your JPanel *(?which is acting as a canvas)*...

Actually, if you want all JPanel(s) be inited at the same time and just get them one by one by some event you can simply use some kind of storage as a Map or List etc, add them all (invisible) to your 'canvas' preferrably FlowLayout manager and make a needed one visible/invisible by an event for example...

Still the major task you trying to achieve is not pretty clear because you do accent Graphics2D so maybe you trying to achieve some another effect ? :S

P.S.
Anyway, it would be better you to show the problem code snippet because your current question contains too less information as for now...

**EDIT**

```
((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[f/27][g/27].getComponent((a/9)*3+b/9)).getComponent((c/3)*3+d/3)).removeAll();
((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[f/27][g/27].getComponent((a/9)*3+b/9)).getComponent((c/3)*3+d/3)).setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[f/27][g/27].getComponent((a/9)*3+b/9)).getComponent((c/3)*3+d/3)).add(miniwin);
((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[f/27][g/27].getComponent((a/9)*3+b/9)).getComponent((c/3)*3+d/3)).repaint();
```

Ok... so that is how you add component to your canvas... As I can see, the array in **Board** is ***static*** object... I may suggest, you have **more than one** canvas object(s)? If yes, it is naturally the ***miniwin(s)*** vanish because static array cannot have shared access by two invokers at a time; so I may recommend **not to use** static field in your case... Please read [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.3.1.1) for more detailed information

---

If you have additional question details please comment

---

Report if that was helpful